# What models exist that explain which people emigrate to another country?

Tags: reference-request, labor-economics, decision-theory

I'm looking for papers about this, or if there's a pretty standard model across many papers, then maybe just a rundown of the model. I'd like to use the model in an econometric analysis.

For example, is there a model that explains whether a more educated person is likely to look for a job abroad versus a less educated person? Or instead of education, a person in a country at war versus a person in a country at peace?

I made an assumption there that the immigrant was seeking a job. Maybe they're looking for other things. I don't care if the model uses that assumption.

I'm doing some research on immigration about the skills immigrants to the US tend to bring and the industries they tend to work in. It would be nice to know if there were a model that showed how factors at home push certain people to certain countries depending on their skills or something.

Comment: The [Harris-Todaro model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harris%E2%80%93Todaro_model). A review of migration theories can be found in the [Journal of Economic Surveys](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-6419.1996.tb00008.x/full).